# Why do I need to do `json.loads` twice to parse a JSON string?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a JSON string with

```
json.loads(json_string)
```

but it returns a string instead of a dict. I can get the expected result by parsing it again

```
json.loads(json.loads(json_string))
```

but I don't understand *why*.

I receive a bytes object from a webhook:

```
bytes_object = b'"{\\"action\\":\\"connection_test\\",\\"data\\":{}}"'
```

The bytes object is then utf-8 decoded:

```
decoded_bytes = bytes_object.decode('utf-8')
"{\"action\":\"connection_test\",\"data\":{}}"
```

Then, the utf-8 decoded object is parsed using json.loads:

```
parsed_once = json.loads(decoded_bytes)
```

But this doesn't return a dict, but a string object looking like this:

```
{"action":"connection_test","data":{}}
```

of type `<class 'str'>`.

But if I parse it again I get the dict expected from the first try:

```
parsed_twice = json.loads(parsed_once)
{'action': 'connection_test', 'data': {}}
```

of type `<class 'dict'>`.

I suspect it's something about how Python 3.9 handles JSON escaping, but I'm not sure. Any help?

Comment: Do you control the webhook's output? Because it seems to be double-encoding the original dict when converting to JSON (similar to the reverse of calling `json.dumps` twice).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I've talked to the developers and told them the same thing. They told me it looks fine. Can you maybe explain how I can see that it's double-encoding?

Comment: From the fact that you need to `json.loads` twice.

Comment: Sure :-) More specifically, as far as I know, the parameter name-quotes shouldn't be escaped, right?

Comment: There's something wonky about the bytes object you receive there. You can see the bytestring's first and last characters (within the quotes) are `"`, so the bytestring indeed is a JSON string that contains a JSON representation of an object.

Comment: The JSON is double encoded, so you need to double-decode it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing, with `json.loads` twice. And it isn't a Python 3.9 problem. The more pressing question is why did the webhook needed to double-encode the data... which isn't answerable in this current state.

Comment: A "regular" JSON object would look like `b'{"action": "connection_test", "data": {}}'`. What you are getting is a JSON object that is encoded *again* to produce a JSON string. The first `json.load` decodes the JSON str into a JSON object; the second decodes the JSON object into a Python `dict`.

Answer (score 9):

The JSON is double encoded, so it needs to be double-decoded. It went something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'action': 'connection_test', 'data': {}}
>>> a = json.dumps(data)
>>> print(a)
{"action": "connection_test", "data": {}}
>>> b = json.dumps(a)
>>> print(b)
"{\"action\": \"connection_test\", \"data\": {}}"
```

That's a mistake that needs to be rectified on the producer side. As long as the producer gives you this double encoded JSON, you need to double decode it.

Comment: Possibly some JavaScript is running JSON.stringify() on something that is already valid JSON.